# How can i set an alert title in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this

```
_matchClassRequest = async () => {
    try{
        if( this.state.address === null ){
            alert(strings.MapScreen_alert_select_address);
            return;
        }
        if( this.state.classRequest === null ){
            alert(strings.MapScreen_select_course);
            return;
        }
```

How can i change the alert title?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert) you can see that you can set an Alert in the following way.

First import the component

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
```

Then you can call it like this: You can set a title and a message. You can choose the number of buttons it has and what each button does (all buttons will dismiss the alert)

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

or simply

```
Alert.alert('Alert Title','My Alert Msg',)
```